# What to look for when selecting a cable for transmitting multiple types of signals in a moving environment

Tags: cables, rs232

I'm working on a device that involves transmitting data between a microcontroller and an IMU device housed on a different PCB. The two are connected via a [cable](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0002J1I28/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) using a [mini DIN connector](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/cui-devices/MD-80SM/96944). I've noticed the cable that's been used for connection tends to wear out pretty quickly and I am looking to find a replacement. However, I'm not precisely sure what I should be looking for in terms of what aspects of a cable would fill the criteria.

the moving PCB will be undergoing movement near-identical to a soldering pencil (I.E. movement can be considered small, but random), and is expected to be used for about two hours a day, five days a week. The connector is an 8-pin connector, though we are only using six pins: two RS232 lines to connect an IMU to a microcontroller, a positive and negative lead for an LRA motor, a +3V3 supply line, and finally a ground connection.

I'm still doing my own research and would appreciate any resources or reading to point me in the right direction or steer me clear of common misconceptions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Look for flex-rated cable.  Then look at the price per foot.  Be certain that your connectors have *excellent*, and properly utilized, strain relief.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen thanks for the advice! Is there a type of flex/motion that fits my description of expected movement to help me narrow it down?

Comment: What are IMU and LRA?  How long is the cable?

Comment: @jonathanjo IMU is an Inertial Measurement Unit; accelerometer, gyroscope, other such sensors. LRA means Linear Resonance Actuator. In this case, it's a haptic feedback motor or buzzer. It's connected to a DRV2605 haptic driver on the main board, with the cable connecting the two leads to the motor on a remote board. Same deal with the IMU, which is connected via RS232 bus running through that same cable

Comment: @jonathanjo Oh, and the length of the cable won't be more than 1.5 meters.

Comment: A very flexible Ethernet cable Cat. 5e 4x2x26/19 AWG specially designed for a dragchain worked for me.

Comment: @Jens Dragchain, like for a 3D printer or something similar? Yeah, that sounds flexible enough. Can you tell me anything about how the individual lines handle EMI? I'm running a motor signal and an RS232 signal through the same cable, so I want to be careful about that

Comment: If you really want to protect the serial signal, convert it to RS422 and run it over a couple of twisted pairs in the Cat5e cable. That should be able to handle most EMI.

Comment: @E.HP.S There are 4 twisted wire pairs. I used a signal and GND in each pair, this was the best assignment.

Comment: @user1937198 I'm already using RS232. Is that enough? To be clear, I'm perfectly happy to switch to 422 later down the line, but I'd like to just stick to getting a different cable for now.

Comment: @Jens I'll take that into consideration for the future. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @E.HP.S Depends. RS-232 is single ended, so you don't get the CMNR of twisted pair differential signalling. Whether that is needed depends on the environment.

Comment: @user1937198 Well, it's worked well so far, and this is something that's intended for use in pretty common places; home, school, office, etc. Honestly, I expect the different signals within the cable to be more of a danger to each other than anything that could be floating around outside of said cable